# Kendo UI Angular Grid - Collapse groups and virtual scroll

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to collapse by default the groups of an Kendo UI Angular Grid with virtual scrolling.

When a column in dragged to the groupping zone, only a group is shown. Only expanding and collapsing the group by hand, the next group becames visible.

```
  <kendo-grid
      [kendoGridGroupBinding]="data"
      [groupable]="true"
      [sortable]="true"
      [pageSize]="80"
      [rowHeight]="35"
      [height]="460"
      scrollable="virtual"
      (groupChange)="groupChange($event)"
    >
    <kendo-grid-column field="id" [width]="80" title="ID"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="firstName" title="First Name" [width]="130"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="lastName" title="Last Name" [width]="130"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="city" title="City" [width]="130"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="title" title="Title" [width]="180"></kendo-grid-column>
  </kendo-grid>



public groupChange(groups: GroupDescriptor[]): void {
  console.log('groupChange', groups);
  this.collapseAllGroups(groups);
}

public collapseAllGroups(groups): void {
    if (this.grid && groups.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        this.grid.collapseGroup(i.toString());
      }
      this.collapsed = true;
    }
}
```

A full example can be found in plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ghVNJlokJwrQ9kRoboWO?p=preview

Is there a way to show all groups collapsed?

Thank's